# How do I return a valid response from an asynchronous method using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Still getting the hang of Node's non-blocking nature.  The following code executes as intended. However, I am wondering if there is a better approach to accomplish the task.

There are 3 params being supplied to the route (zipcode, type, rad).
From there I use the NPM Zipcode package to return an array of zipcodes within the provided rad.

I am then using a for loop on the zips array within an async function and awaiting the response of a function which performs a MySQL query and returns a promise. Then returning an array of user objects.

My uncertainty is whether I am sending the response correctly or if there is a more efficient way to write this code.

Thanks.

```js
router.get('/:zipcode/:type/:rad', function (req, res) {

  const rad = req.params.rad;
  const zip = req.params.zipcode;
  let zips = zipcodes.radius(zip, rad);
  zips.push(zip);

  let type;
  if(req.params.type === 'bartenders') {
    type = 0;
  } else {
    type = 1;
  }

  const params = {
    'type': type,
    'zips': zips
  };


  function userGroup(type, zip) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM bt9.users WHERE zip = ${zip} AND type = ${type} AND display = 1`, function (err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }


  async function getUsers(params) {
    let userList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < params.zips.length; i++) {
      const users = await userGroup(params.type, params.zips[i]);
      for (u = 0; u < users.length; u++) {
        userList.push(users[u]);
      }
    }
    return userList;
  }


  function sendUsers(callback) {
    getUsers(params).then( res => {
      callback(null, res)
    })
  }


  sendUsers(function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(result)
  })


});
```

Answer (score 7):

**Express 5 will automatically handle async errors correctly**

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html currently says it clearly:

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error. For example:
>
> ```
> app.get('/user/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
>  var user = await getUserById(req.params.id)
>  res.send(user)
> })
> ```
>
> If getUserById throws an error or rejects, next will be called with either the thrown error or the rejected value. If no rejected value is provided, next will be called with a default Error object provided by the Express router.

I have shown that in an experiment at: [Passing in Async functions to Node.js Express.js router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813401/passing-in-async-functions-to-node-js-express-js-router/67689269#67689269)

This means that you will be able to just make the callback `async` and use `await` from it directly without any extra wrappers:

```
router.get('/:zipcode/:type/:rad', async (req) => {
  ...
  return await getUsers({ type, zips });
});
```

Note that as of December 2021, Express 5 is still in alpha release, not recommended for production use.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of converting every callback function to Promise manually, it is easier to create a wrapper to support async/await.

> Reference
>   https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/

```js
function asyncWrapper(fn) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise.resolve(fn(req))
      .then((result) => res.send(result))
      .catch((err) => next(err))
  }
}
```

**Example Code**

```js
async createUser(req) {
  const user = await User.save(req.body)
  return user
}

router.post('/users', asyncWrapper(createUser))
```

**Refactoring Your Code**

```js
function userGroup(type, zip) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM bt9.users WHERE zip = ${zip} AND type = ${type} AND display = 1`, function (err, result) {
      if(err) throw err;
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

async function getUsers({ type, zips }) {
  let userList = [];
  // [IMPORTANT]
  // - Replaced the for-loop to for-of-loop for await to work.
  // - This is not efficient because the `userGroup` function is run one by one serially.
  for (let zip of zips) {
    const users = await userGroup(type, zip);
    userList = userList.concat(users);
  }
  return userList;
}

router.get('/:zipcode/:type/:rad', asyncWrapper(async (req) => {
  const rad = req.params.rad;
  const zip = req.params.zipcode;
  let zips = zipcodes.radius(zip, rad);
  zips.push(zip);

  let type;
  if(req.params.type === 'bartenders') {
    type = 0;
  } else {
    type = 1;
  }

  return await getUsers({ type, zips });
}));
```

To further improve the efficiency, you should replace the for-of-loop inside `getUsers` with `Promise.map` offered by [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html). `Promise.map` will run the promises in parallel.

```js
async function getUsers({ type, zips }) {
  let userList = []
  const userListList = await Promise.map(zips, (zip) => {
    return userGroup(type, zip);
  });
  for (let users of userListList) {
    userList = userList.concat(users)
  }
  return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not throw an error when you are not inside an async function.

```
function userGroup(type, zip) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM bt9.users WHERE zip = ${zip} AND type = ${type} AND display = 1`, function (err, result) {
        if(err) return reject(err); //<- reject and return
        resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
```

Also, you can use `Promise.all` with an array of promises instead of `await` inside each loop iteration. That would allow for parallel execution to your connection.

Answer (score -1):

To add on to [Steven Spungin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897220/8550747) here's the `getUsers` function refactored with `Promise.all`:

```
function getUsers({zips, type}) {
  return Promise.all(zips.map(zip => userGroup(type, zip)))
    .then(users => users.flat());
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind using a third-party module, you could drop in [`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af) and make use of its [`mapAF`](https://async-af.js.org/AsyncAF#mapAF) (alias `map`) method:

```
const aaf = require('async-af');
// ...
async function getUsers({zips, type}) {
  const userGroups = await aaf(zips).map(zip => userGroup(type, zip));
  return userGroups.flat(); // flat isn't yet part of 'async-af' but now that it's finalized for ES, I'm sure it'll be added soon.
}
```